# How to read only one column from csv file using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, powershell-2.0

I'm working on powershell script and I'm trying to read only "User" column from my csv file and then convert it to their Microsoft AzureAD Display name but not sure how to do that so I'll be appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion.

My csv file look like this

C:\AuditLogSearch$($CurDate) Final Audit-Log-Records.csv

```
User       Date &Time       Activity
-------------------------------------
abc@gmail.com   11/22/2021     play soccer
kei@gmail.com   10/22/2021     play football
def@gmail.com   11/22/2021     play soccer
def@gmail.com   09/22/2021     play Baseball
xyz@gmail.com   08/22/2021     play soccer
klm@gmail.com   19/22/2021     play football
```

```
function Connect-AzureActiveDirectory {
    $pso = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck:$true -SkipCNCheck:$true -SkipRevocationCheck:$true -OperationTimeout 180000 -ProxyAccessType AutoDetect
    Connect-AzureAD -Credential $credential -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/PowerShell-LiveID -PSSessionOption $pso
    $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Exchange Online - NAM Production Beta MFA"
    Write-Host "Connected to Azure AD"      
}


function Convert-UserColumn {
    $ImportFile = "C:\AuditLogSearch\$($CurDate) Final Audit-Log-Records.csv"
    $ExportFile = "C:\AuditLogSearch\FinalFile.csv"

// I'm struggling with the logic here

    $list = @() foreach ($u in $ImportFile.User) {
        $list += Get-AzureDisplayName -mail $u
        
    }

    Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId 

   | Export-Csv $ExportFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Trying to make the Final Export csv file should look like this
C:\AuditLogSearch\FinalFile.csv

```
User       Date &Time       Activity
-------------------------------------
Jonathan Sparkle   11/22/2021     play soccer

Randy Mod       10/22/2021     play football
Hanah P         11/22/2021     play soccer
Hanah P         09/22/2021     play Baseball
Cristiano Ronaldo   08/22/2021     play soccer
Leo Messi    19/22/2021     play football
```

Comment: Hi, I saw your comment, now its deleted. Can you explain the issue again? Did you make sure there are no duplicated UserPrincipalNames?

Comment: oh ok I think It was my mistake. My import file was wrong and I think it's working now.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon can you pls help me with another one pls, I'm trying to change the Activity column value/text. for example if text = play soccer then change it to "play futball", text = "play football" then change it to "play rugby" and so on..

Comment: See my update, please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just update the values on the `User` property of the imported CSV, there is no need to create a `$list = @()` to save the results.

Assuming `$ImportFile.User` contains valid `UserPrincipalNames` of Azure AD Users, the part you're struggling with would look like this (definitely no need for a function):

```
$ImportFile = Import-Csv "C:\AuditLogSearch\$($CurDate) Final Audit-Log-Records.csv"
$ExportFile = "C:\AuditLogSearch\FinalFile.csv"

foreach ($u in $ImportFile) {
    $u.User = (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $u.User).DisplayName
}

$ImportFile | Export-Csv $ExportFile -NoTypeInformation
```

---

*I'm trying to change the Activity column value/text. For example if text = "play soccer" then change it to "play futball" or if text = "play football" then change it to "play rugby" and so on..*

This would require `if` conditions or a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2). i.e.:

```
# Using this as an Example
$csv = @'
User,Date & Time,Activity
abc@gmail.com,11/22/2021,play soccer
kei@gmail.com,10/22/2021,play football
def@gmail.com,11/22/2021,play soccer
def@gmail.com,09/22/2021,play Baseball
xyz@gmail.com,08/22/2021,play soccer
klm@gmail.com,19/22/2021,play football
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

foreach($line in $csv)
{
    $line.Activity = switch($line.Activity)
    {
        'play soccer' { 'play futball'; break }
        'play football' { 'play rugby'; break }
        Default { $_ } # If no matches, leave it as is
    }
}

$csv | Format-Table
```

```
User          Date & Time Activity
----          ----------- --------
abc@gmail.com 11/22/2021  play futball
kei@gmail.com 10/22/2021  play rugby
def@gmail.com 11/22/2021  play futball
def@gmail.com 09/22/2021  play Baseball
xyz@gmail.com 08/22/2021  play futball
klm@gmail.com 19/22/2021  play rugby
```